# Audio Clicks/Pops from Filter Code

Tags: c#, audio, filter, signal-processing, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a C# script for audio filters in the Unity engine.

My problem is that the after being run through my filter, the resulting audio has consistent and frequent "clicks", "pops", or "skips". It sounds a bit like an old radio. 
I'm not sure what's causing this.

Here's my code:

```
public float cutoff;
public float resonance;

int sampleRate;

void Start()
{
    cutoff = 200;
    resonance = 1;

    sampleRate = AudioSettings.outputSampleRate;
}

void OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)
{
    float c = 2 * Mathf.PI * cutoff/sampleRate;
    float r = 1 / resonance;

    float v0 = 0;
    float v1 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        v0 =  (1 - r * c) * v0  -  (c) * v1  + (c) * data[i];
        v1 =  (1 - r * c) * v1  +  (c) * v0;

        data[i] = v1;
    }
}
```

Here is the documentation for [OnAudioFilterRead()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnAudioFilterRead.html).

Here is where I got the [original low-pass code](http://musicdsp.org/showArchiveComment.php?ArchiveID=185).

As the cutoff nears its maximum value (127), the clicks and pops become quieter.

I'm rather new to audio programming, as may be evident, so I'm not sure what would be causing it.

Could someone more knowledgeable than me explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I should also add that, other than the clicks and pops, the filter sounds fine.

Comment: I've found where the pops likely reside. If I output a chunk of samples when I hear the clicks/buzz and after filtering it, I see a lot of numbers like 4.739146e-05 (positive and negative). What (probably in my algorithm) might be the cause of these numbers, and/or how would I go about fixing them? Thanks for reading.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it. My c and r variables needed to persist throughout calls to OnAudioFilterRead(). Making them members fixed it. Here is my complete, working code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class LowPassFilter : MonoBehaviour {

    public float cutoff;
    public float resonance;

    const float CUTOFF_MAX = 128.0f;
    const float CUTOFF_MIN = 0.0f;
    const float RESONANCE_MAX = 128.0f;
    const float RESONANCE_MIN = 0.0f;

    float c;
    float r;
    float v0;
    float v1;

    int sampleRate;

    void Start()
    {
        cutoff = 20.0f;
        resonance = 0.0f;

        c = 0.0f;
        r = 0.0f;
        v0 = 0.0f;
        v1 = 0.0f;

        sampleRate = AudioSettings.outputSampleRate;
    }

    void OnAudioFilterRead(float[] data, int channels)
    {
        cutoff = Mathf.Clamp(cutoff, CUTOFF_MIN, CUTOFF_MAX);
        resonance = Mathf.Clamp(resonance, RESONANCE_MIN, RESONANCE_MAX);

        c = Mathf.Pow(0.5f, (128.0f - cutoff) / 16.0f);
        r = Mathf.Pow(0.5f, (resonance + 24.0f) / 16.0f);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            v0 =  ((1.0f - r * c) * v0)  -  (c * v1)  + (c * data[i]);
            v1 =  ((1.0f - r * c) * v1)  +  (c * v0);

            data[i] = Mathf.Clamp(v1, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Common causes of clicks and pops (in order of 'commonness') are:

- wrong buffer length (you overlapped the buffer or failed to fill it to the boundary)
- your sample are clipping, and you don't handle it like you should - for example you are calculating everything in `short`s, and don't care about wrapping the values
- your DSP algorithm is behaving badly
- your algorithm is too slow for some reason, and audio sample isn't delivered in time, causing audio gaps

One good debugging technique for this is to try to narrow down the cause of the problem by, for example, inserting PCM dumping directly inside the routine that processes the audio.  That way, you'll know if the output of your routine is OK or not, and be able to focus your debugging efforts accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

I've managed to rule out the second and fourth possibilities you posed, as Unity provides me with a handy VU meter for the audio post-filter, and a box which tells me if my filter is taking up too much time.

As for possibility 1, I don't think that's the issue, because OnAudioFilterRead() is a callback that gives me a pre-set chunk of data.

I think possibility 3 is the most likely. The problem with that, though, is I don't know where it would be going wrong.

Comment: Ugh, when copying code for a filter, you completely ignored SECOND post where relation between sampleFreq and your filter constants are explained and calculated.  So your filter works in a extremely low or extremely high frequency range, depending on the direction in which calculation of constants go.

Comment: I have tried using and tweaking the code from the second post already. The issue remains. As I said in my post, I am very new to audio programming. I could be overlooking something simple.

Comment: Simple is that you don't use SAMPLE RATE anywhere.  Think about it - filter code can't operate on ANY sample rate, so sample rate should be used somehow.  Now, see how to use it - using second post from link you used to find the code.

Comment: I have already tried using that code, but I tried again anyways. I've edited my original post to reflect what I am doing now. The static/pops are still there.